# Which screen type is clearer, and why?

Tags: user-behavior, navigation, psychology, drawer

I know it's a dead-simple and an incredibly clear UI, but my question is when it comes to **familiarity** as the extension of the principle of **clarity**, which makes the good UI/UX to the user?

Why centered:
Since the drawer header is not a part of the drawer items we can take it out and keep it isolated in a **centric manner**.

Why left-aligned:
As humans, we read from **left to right** because we write from left to right.

So I am concerned about both UI and want to know which one will be best for users.

If none is a good UX then what do you guys suggest? Keep in mind that I am more concerned about the header part of the UI.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll find much difference but as always, test your designs to find out!

Comment: I think this will really make very little difference in the end, it's just visual preference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are concerned about familiarity you should structure your component left-aligned as 99% of other sidebar-account-header-components.

It also creates a consistency of reading-flow from left i.e. icon or profile image to right i.e. micro-copy name. E.g. the user doesn't have to change his reading or eye movement flow or direction when looking at all the elements in the sidebar consequentially.

Lastly it needs less space and therefore is the more concise version.